# React-native ios app is not responding

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

when i install the ios app , app screen is not responding. After refreshing and clear the background process the app is working fine.

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you'll need to include some code or more details as to what is happening. It sounds like you have some code that is failing on initialization but is not depended upon for the rest of the app. If you run `react-native log-ios` from the command line in your repo, do you get any interesting messages that might contribute to the unresponsiveness?

Comment: >: Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Aug 23 01:13:30 Sivagamasundaris-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.359EA36C-54A2-4155-8326-1F146641A8ED[475] (com.apple.videosubscriptionsd[3988]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1       i'm getting this issue when i run the "react-native log-ios"

Comment: Do you have xcode configured correctly according to the docs? It seems like it's not react native, but the way you have it set up. Have you tried starting another project? Are you running from expo?